# Getting a reloading json jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

What's wrong with my code?

The `GET` works and so does the `setInterval` function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var dta = $('#csd')
    setInterval(function(){ $.ajax({
        url: 'jason/jason_data.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType : "json",
        data:dta,
        success : function (dta){
            if (JSON.stringify(dta)!== cdata){
                cdata = JSON.stringify(dta);
             $('#csd').append(JSON.stringify(data_response));
                }
            }
        })

},5000);

 </script>
<div id="csd">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data_response and cdata are both undefined among other issues, stringify the data you send, un-dupicate vareables, un nest the function to make more clear